# Regex pattern allowing alphabets, numbers, decimals, spaces and underscore

Tags: c#, java, php, javascript, regex

I am not good with regular expression patterns.
I have to put a validation on an string, to allow

```
only alphabets, numbers, decimals, spaces, comma and underscore
```

for allowing the alphabets and spaces I have `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]+$/`
Please help me in creating all the above conditions in one pattern.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you added a jQuery tag... And what is the difference between numbers and decimals.

Comment: Is "decimals" the decimal point? I added it, just in case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this regex should work for your requirements

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9_. ,]*'
```

In the regex, I specified the range a to z, A to Z (uppercase), 0 to 9 and the single character _, decimal point ".", space and a comma.

If you want to make sure you want at least one character after the first letter, you can replace the * with a +, or {2,} with at least 2 more characters, or {2,5} with between 2 and 5 characters.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, 
Thanks for your prompt reply, let me check this

Comment: `\s` is more than just "space". It matches any whitespace character: tab, space, new line, carriage return, and I think 2 other character.

Comment: as he asked for "spaces", I covered all whitespaces but in case, the requirement is of just a "space", I have changed the regex

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
/^[\w., ]+$/
```

I don't know what are the requirements for the starting char, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul's answer gave me the direction to think, but for the visitors, may be this too can be helpfull

```
patternForClasName      =   /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9 _]+$/;  
// Allowing valid className which has a format abcsasa.dsd.dsd(the class or a package name can have an underscore or a numerical)

patternForName          =   /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
// Allowing alphanumeric + spaces + (_)underscore and a (-)dash

patternForDescription   =   /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+[\,\.]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]*$/;
  // Allowing alphanumeric,spaces, (_)underscore, (-)dash, comma, decimal

patternURLFormat        = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

// For a valid URL
```